# Pulseaudio lags horribly only when Android Studio is running

Tags: sound, pulseaudio, android-studio, 19.10

I've got a very weird problem - my audio works perfectly, even under **massive** CPU load, but as soon as I start the Android Studio IDE, it becomes super laggy and distorted with glitches, cracks and pops. And this problem **only** occurs with Android Studio, and no other program!

I tried a lot of things:

- Disabling timer-based scheduling
- Giving pulseaudio better niceness value
- Enabling realtime settings
- Trying another sound card
- Trying other Java applications, they don't show the same problem
- Disallow resampling
- Setting the default sample rate
- Trying out IntelliJ IDEA, since Android Studio is based on that. The problem does **not** appear here.

Nothing fixed the issue. Does anybody know a solution for this?

My specs are:

- Amd Ryzen 9 3900X 12 core CPU
- 32 GB DDR4 RAM
- Main drive is a M.2 SSD

P.S. I'm **not** using the Android emulator, **just** the IDE

Comment: Android studio needs some RAM, so it's possible that your computer is swapping because Android studio (+ other loaded programs) are filling the RAM, and pulseaudio must use swapped RAM (I experimented that with a 4 Go RAM computer, Android Studio + Chrome were filling almost 3 Go/ 4 Go, add Windows programs - *I code on Windows for Java, sorry :(* ). Best thing to share is your computer specs as **RAM** + **CPU**

Comment: @damadam Its definitely not the RAM, as I have 32GB and its only 4GB full when the problems occur. I added the specs :)

Comment: Does this happen just opening Android Studio or actually doing something with it?

Comment: @WinEunuuchs2Unix It happens on just opening Android Studio with a project. I don't even have to click anything. Weird thing is that Android Studio is based on the IntelliJ IDE, and that one does not give me these problems.

Comment: Does it happen without opening your project?

Comment: Did you check your initial RAM and max RAM setting for Android Studio? [Android Studio is incredibly slow and laggy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37703866/android-studio-is-incredibly-slow-and-laggy)

Comment: When you say Android IDE, does it mean that a project is loaded or is it just Android Studio showing you a list of projects to open? Also, what happens when you open more than one instance of Android Studio (as in open another project in Android Studio and click on New Window when it asks where you want this project to open)?

Comment: Android Studio should not be using as much memory to distort the audio as you are saying. And it is clearly not related to Ubuntu as well.

Comment: I'd say I have almost the same problem when opening AS, but my problem is that mouse became laggy for some reason(you move mouse across screen and it's start freezing with almost same periods of time, like some process is probing something). I have similar specs, using Ubuntu and just opening AS with project introduces the problem. Windows's AS on other hand doesn't have this problem.

Comment: I have identical issue. Glitches from all audio players (spotify, google music, lollipop, ...) right after opening AS. 32Gb memory, ssd. No emulator started. Tons of free memory. Started happening when updated to ubuntu 19.*, still getting on fresh 20.04.  @nshct, did you find solution?

Comment: I've faced with the same issue. I see no answers here, so I'm trying to investigate with attraction affected projects: * https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-252399
* https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/170230081
* https://gitlab.freedesktop.org/pulseaudio/pulseaudio/-/issues/1003

Comment: Just discovered that I have this issue only when external DAC is involved (I have 2 DACs from FiiO). When switched to HDMI audio (nvidia) - no issues.
So, maybe this issue is somehow related to USB Audio, since it's *Isochronous* and it does not guarantee data integrity, it can identify if data is corrupted (via CRC check) but can not recover an error.

Answer (score 6):

Finally I found the root of the issue - it's the ADB daemon.

Killing the daemon fix the problem, but AS will restart it anyway (and for sure it's a bad solution).

The right way is to check the **Use libusb backend** option in **Settings > Build, Execution, Deployment > Debugger > Android Debug Bridge**

TIP: You can search for "Use libusb backend" in settings window to find it quickly.

Comment: Reviewers please don't keep closing this answer. It also looks like an answer to me because of [Why does adb have a high CPU usage](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5702817/)?

Comment: Enabling it fixed the audio crackling, not even a restart needed, on Arch kernel 5.17.4

Comment: Three years later this answer saved me months of wrestling with this issue. Thank you very much, I would upvote you 100 times if I could.